# How to put biff8 contents to clipboard via Java code for pasting it to excel file (requirement is to paste a table to excel without losing its format)

Tags: java, excel, biff

How to put biff8 contents to clipboard via Java code for pasting it to excel file (requirement is to paste a table to excel without losing its format)

This requirement comes in my Java swing project.